# .Net Core / Identity Server - Is it possible to AllowAnonymous but only from my client?

Tags: asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, identityserver4, openid-connect

I have a REST API and an IdentityServer set up. I would like to be able to display items in my client from the API without having to sign in. However, I would also like to protect my API from external clients that don't belong to me. Is it possible to AllowAnonymous but only from my client?

```
[HttpGet]
[AllowAnonymous]
public List<Item> GetItems()
{
    return new List<Item> { "item1", "item2" };
}
```

**Edit w/ Solution**
As mentioned by Tore Nestenius, I changed the grant types from Code to CodeAndClientCredentials and added the Authorize attribute to my controller so that only my client can access it.

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
[Authorize]
public List<Item> GetItems()
{
    return new List<Item> { "item1", "item2" };
```

Identity Server 4 Config File:

```
public static IEnumerable<Client> Clients =>
    new Client[] 
    {
        new Client
        {
            ClientId = "postman-api",
            AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.CodeAndClientCredentials,
            ClientSecrets =
            {
                    new Secret("secret".Sha256())
            },
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CORS only works for requests from browsers, if a non browser application makes a request, then CORS will not be involved.

if you use [AllowAnonymous], then any client can access that API endpoint. Either you create separate client for the general things, perhaps using the Client Credentials flow, so that the client can authenticate, get its own token without any user involved.

Comment: Yes, I forgot about the other flows mainly because they aren't talked about as much. I'll read into that one and the other ones to see which one fits best.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I updated the question to include the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this is handled by CORS.

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddDefaultPolicy(
                    builder => builder
                        .WithOrigins("yourURL")
                        .AllowAnyMethod());
            })
     }
```